Create a similar matrix object in matlab and python
For comparison purposes, I want to create an object which would have the same shape and indexing properties in matlab and python (numpy).
Let's say that on the matlab side the object would be :
arr_matlab = cat(4, ...
    cat(3, ...
        [  1,   2;
           3,   4;
           5,   6], ...
        [  7,   8;
           9,  10;
          11,  12], ...
        [ 13,  14;
          15,  16;
          17,  18], ...
        [ 20,  21;
          22,  23;
          24,  25]), ...
    cat(3, ...
        [ 26,  27;
          28,  29;
          30,  31], ...
        [ 32,  33;
          34,  35;
          36,  37], ...
        [ 38,  39;
          40,  41;
          42,  43], ...
        [ 44,  45;
          46,  47;
          48,  49]), ...
    cat(3, ...
        [ 50,  51;
          52,  53;
          54,  55], ...
        [ 56,  57;
          58,  59;
          60,  61], ...
        [ 62,  63;
          64,  65;
          66,  67], ...
        [ 68,  69;
          70,  71;
          72,  73]), ...
    cat(3, ...
        [ 74,  75;
          76,  77;
          78,  79], ...
        [ 80,  81;
          82,  83;
          84,  85], ...
        [ 86,  87;
          88,  89;
          90,  91], ...
        [ 92,  93;
          94,  95;
          96,  97]), ...
    cat(3, ...
        [ 98,  99;
         100, 101;
         102, 103], ...
        [104, 105;
         106, 107;
         108, 109], ...
        [110, 111;
         112, 113;
         114, 115], ...
        [116, 117;
         118, 119;
         120, 121]));
K>> size(arr_matlab)

ans =

     3     2     4     5

K>> arr_matlab(1, 2, 1 ,1)

ans =

     2

size(arr_matlab) should be identical to arr_python.shape and indexing should give the same result (same result for arr_python[0,1,0,0] and arr_matlab(1,2,1,1) for example).
For the moment I can't do it.
data = np.array([
     ...:     1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25,
     ...:     26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49,
     ...:     50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73,
     ...:     74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97,
     ...:     98, 99, 100, 101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 106, 107, 108, 109, 110, 111, 112, 113, 114, 115, 116, 117, 118, 119, 120, 121
     ...: ])
     ...: 
     ...: # Reshape to 3x2x4x5
     ...: arr_python = data.reshape((3, 2, 4, 5), order='F')
In [138]: arr_python.shape
Out[138]: (3, 2, 4, 5)
 arr_python[0,1,0,0]
Out[143]: 4


This is what you're trying to achieve in Python and MatLab:
MatLab
arr_matlab = reshape(1:120, [3, 2, 4, 5]);
L = size(arr_matlab);
disp(L);
disp(arr_matlab(1, 2, 1, 1));

Prints
3   2   4   5

4

Python
import numpy as np

data = np.arange(1, 120 + 1)
arr_python = data.reshape((3, 2, 4, 5), order='F')
print(arr_python.shape)
print(arr_python[0, 1, 0, 0])


Prints
(3, 2, 4, 5)
4


Comments:

Note that Python's end range is not inclusive.

You could simplify data = np.array(list(range(1, 120 + 1))) to data = np.arange(1, 120 + 1) in the Python version.

Python’s F ordering is reversed from its C ordering. But this doesn’t match MATLAB’s ordering. If Python’s C ordering is indexed as a,b,c,d, then MATLAB’s ordering is c,d,b,a. It’s weird, I know. Test your code with more than that one indexing operation, you might find discrepancies. – Cris Luengo

OK, my comment above relates to the interpretation of axes in MATLAB and Python, but not about the storage order, which is what this question is about. I did test the indexing for this solution, and it does match. – Cris Luengo



exactly what I was looking for! Thanks.

Python’s F ordering is reversed from its C ordering. But this doesn’t match MATLAB’s ordering. If Python’s C ordering is indexed as a,b,c,d, then MATLAB’s ordering is c,d,b,a. It’s weird, I know. Test your code with more than that one indexing operation, you might find discrepancies.

OK, my comment above relates to the interpretation of axes in MATLAB and Python, but not about the storage order, which is what this question is about. I did test the indexing for this solution, and it does match.
